# Top ten best ways of transportation

Tags: cipher, steganography

<sub>This is an entry into the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet).</sub>

Last night me and my friends had a fun night at the bar. When it was time for us to leave, we couldn't come up with a transport that will be comfortable and fit our status the most. After a while we came up with the following list of candidates (left to right on the picture):

[image: all of them here]

> Oyster 
>  Wild retard Steve 
>  Korn Ferry owner 
>  Bears 
>  Daemons 
>  Croach 
>  This bowtie 
>  AXA editor 
>  Nacho 
>  Doritos

As we are still in the bar arguing, could you resolve our conundrum? What transport would satisfy our needs?

Comment: Daemons or demons ? One is a Unix background process, the other a malevolent spirit.

Comment: @Phylyp The wording is correct; there are also living entities called "daemons" - it's slightly different from demon (quotation needed), but still.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that earlier, Google has now educated me :)

Comment: A great question well done @ThomasBlue

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I started creating it exactly for the challenge, but than thought it's overly complicated. Now I probably will.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Each picture has one or more numbers. Taking the nth letter from each image's description:
>
>  Oys**t**er (4)
>  Wild ret**a**rd Steve (8)
>  **K**orn F**e**rry owner (1, 6)
>  B**e**ars (2)
>  D**a**emons (2)
>  Croa**c**h (5)
>  T**h**i**s** bowt**i**e (2, 4, 9)
>  A**X**A edi**t**or (2, 7)
>  Nac**h**o (4)
>  Doritos (-)
>
>  Which spells **take each sixth**...
>
>  Each sixth letter from the words spells **RETRY BACTWARDS** (small typo there?)
>
>  Starting from the end, it spells **ONE THREE ONE TWO**
>
>  Which is **1312**, or in A1Z26... **A CAB**

Comment: This was an impressive piece of work, well done jafe!!

Comment: Great thought well done @jafe

Comment: @jafe Man that's fast (also, damn that typo, I was so close to making a flawless puzzle). I'll add the tick later, if you don't mind.

Comment: So, the final answer is "start trouble, get a ride [in the back of a police cruiser](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=1312)" then? :-)